# Ktx2 loader: Unexpected identifier ‘html’

Tags: three.js

I’m trying to load a ktx2 texture, but I get this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'html' (at
> be60c27b-a185-4e22-a763-bad0f7c717e0:6:11)

The error points to the html tag:

```
/* constants */
let _EngineFormat = {"RGBAFormat":1023,"RGBA_ASTC_4x4_Format":37808,"RGBA_BPTC_Format":36492,"RGBA_ETC2_EAC_Format":37496,"RGBA_PVRTC_4BPPV1_Format":35842,"RGBA_S3TC_DXT5_Format":33779,"RGB_ETC1_Format":36196,"RGB_ETC2_Format":37492,"RGB_PVRTC_4BPPV1_Format":35840,"RGB_S3TC_DXT1_Format":33776}
let _TranscoderFormat = {"ETC1":0,"ETC2":1,"BC1":2,"BC3":3,"BC4":4,"BC5":5,"BC7_M6_OPAQUE_ONLY":6,"BC7_M5":7,"PVRTC1_4_RGB":8,"PVRTC1_4_RGBA":9,"ASTC_4x4":10,"ATC_RGB":11,"ATC_RGBA_INTERPOLATED_ALPHA":12,"RGBA32":13,"RGB565":14,"BGR565":15,"RGBA4444":16}
let _BasisFormat = {"ETC1S":0,"UASTC_4x4":1}
/* basis_transcoder.js */
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
```

I’m using webpack and I’m loading the texture as follows:

```
import {KTX2Loader} from 'three/addons/loaders/KTX2Loader.js';
import test from '../../../../assets/models/test.ktx2';

this.ktx2Loader = new KTX2Loader();
this.ktx2Loader.setTranscoderPath('../utils/decoders/basis');
this.ktx2Loader.detectSupport( this.renderer );

const texture = await this.ktx2Loader.loadAsync(test);
```

Both js and wasm requests for the basis_transcoder return a 307 Temporary Redirect.

three r150

Comment: This kind of error usually means that a necessary file is not at the expected URL, and your webserver returned an HTML "Not found" page instead. The code is not the problem, it's the relative structure of the files vs. the URL given in `setTranscoderPath`. You may need to check those more carefully, and look at your browser's Network tab in developer tools, to see if it's getting the Basis decoders at the right path — as a first guess, you may need a trailing slash on `../utils/decoders/basis/`.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy unfortunately the trailing slash didn't fix it. 
The html is not from a 404 page but from the actual website.
The script seems to insert the parameters at the top of the page and the worker script below it.
What I see in the network tab is that both the js and wasm requests for the basis_transcoder return a 307 Temporary Redirect.

Comment: That's a good sign they're the wrong URLs, but I don't have your whole directory structure to tell you the correct ones, unfortunately. If you're using a build system like Webpack or Vite, you may need to put these files in a static or "public" directory, rather than a source code directory.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy Now it works! I'm using FastAPI and I am redirecting all 404's to the homepage.. So all I had to do was to register both paths to the transcoders and return the files, done. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution on a Yuri Artiukh video, I'm only working on this locally but it fixed the problem for me.

```js
import * as THREE from "three"
import { REVISION } from "three"

const THREE_PATH = `https://unpkg.com/three@0.${REVISION}.x`
const ktx2Loader = new KTX2Loader()
ktx2Loader.setTranscoderPath(`${THREE_PATH}/examples/jsm/libs/basis/`)
ktx2Loader.detectSupport(this.renderer)
    
// after you have a mesh and its been added to the scene something like this should now work
    
ktx2Loader.load(tDiffuse, (texture) => {
  material.uniforms.uDiffuse.value = texture
})
```